# TextFormFIeld only takes input on second tap and ignore input on first tap

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, textfield, stream-builder

****Context**
I am reading data from Firebase Firsestore subcollection, and am passing that to a page, which displays all the information as a customized tile. This tile on clicking gives us the ability to able to edit the details within the data of the document inside the subcollection. The form which pops up on clicking the tile, has one dropdown box, one textformfield and 2 date pickers. Everything else is able to change the value withing them, except the textformfield. *

*Firebase Firestore Setup**
Users>docID>Statuses>statusID

I am facing this weird error, where I cannot seem to type anything in the TextFormField box on a page on first click, I have to click it the second time to be able to type into it. When I do type into it and hit enter on the android emulator device, the text which I just entered vanishes and just displays whatever I just had before.

On trying to tap twice and enter the text value, it resets all other features of the form to its original value before edit. So I am now forced to save to firebase on each change. This keeps all other fields from not changing, but the TextFormField still does not work!

*As for the program flow:
status_detailed_screen_tab --> update_status_screen
*

I will highlight the code which send the information to the update screen.

**status_detailed_screen_tab**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:prototype_1/screens/add_new_status_screen.dart';
import 'package:prototype_1/screens/update_status_screen.dart';
import 'package:prototype_1/util/text_styles/text_style.dart';
import 'package:prototype_1/util/tiles/current_status_detailed_screen_tile.dart';
import 'package:prototype_1/util/tiles/past_status_detailed_screen_tile.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

late Stream<QuerySnapshot> documentStream;
List<Map<String, dynamic>> userCurrentStatus = [];

class StatusesTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const StatusesTab({
    super.key,
    required this.docID,
  });

  final String docID;

  @override
  State<StatusesTab> createState() => _StatusesTabState();
}

class _StatusesTabState extends State<StatusesTab> {
  //This is what the stream builder is waiting for

  @override
  void initState() {
    documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(widget.docID)
        .collection('Statuses')
        .snapshots();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> userPastStatus = [];
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> toRemove = [];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0.sp),
        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: documentStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var users = snapshot.data?.docs.toList();
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              userCurrentStatus = [];
              userPastStatus = [];
              toRemove = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < users!.length; i++) {
                var data = users[i].data();
                userCurrentStatus.add(data as Map<String, dynamic>);
                userCurrentStatus[i]
                    .addEntries({'ID': users[i].reference.id}.entries);
              }
              for (var status in userCurrentStatus) {
                if (DateFormat("d MMM yyyy")
                    .parse(status['endDate'])
                    .isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
                  userPastStatus.add(status);
                  toRemove.add(status);
                }
              }
              userCurrentStatus
                  .removeWhere((element) => toRemove.contains(element));
            }
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.medical_information_rounded,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30.sp,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.w,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Active Statuses",
                      maxLines: 2,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        letterSpacing: 1.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 295.h,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: userCurrentStatus.length,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.sp),
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ***UpdateStatusScreen(
                                statusID: userCurrentStatus[index]['ID'],
                                docID: widget.docID,
                                selectedStatusType: userCurrentStatus[index]
                                    ['statusType'],
                                statusName: TextEditingController(
                                    text: userCurrentStatus[index]['statusName']
                                        .toString()),
                                startDate: userCurrentStatus[index]
                                    ['startDate'],
                                endDate: userCurrentStatus[index]['endDate'],
                              ),***
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: SoldierStatusTile(
                          statusID: userCurrentStatus[index]['ID'],
                          docID: widget.docID,
                          statusType: userCurrentStatus[index]['statusType'],
                          statusName: userCurrentStatus[index]['statusName'],
                          startDate: userCurrentStatus[index]['startDate'],
                          endDate: userCurrentStatus[index]['endDate'],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.av_timer_rounded,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30.sp,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.w,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Past Statuses",
                      maxLines: 2,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        letterSpacing: 1.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: userPastStatus.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return PastSoldierStatusTile(
                        statusID: userPastStatus[index]['ID'],
                        docID: widget.docID,
                        statusType: userPastStatus[index]['statusType'],
                        statusName: userPastStatus[index]['statusName'],
                        startDate: userPastStatus[index]['startDate'],
                        endDate: userPastStatus[index]['endDate'],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.h,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AddNewStatusScreen(
                            docID: widget.docID,
                            selectedStatusType: "Select status type...",
                            statusName: TextEditingController(),
                            startDate:
                                DateFormat('d MMM yyyy').format(DateTime.now()),
                            endDate:
                                DateFormat('d MMM yyyy').format(DateTime.now()),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 40.0.w, vertical: 16.0.h),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          gradient: const LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 72, 30, 229),
                              Color.fromARGB(255, 130, 60, 229),
                            ],
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0.r)),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.note_add,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 30.sp,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20.w,
                          ),
                          StyledText("ADD NEW STATUS", 18.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**update_status_screen**

```
// ignore_for_file: must_be_immutable
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:prototype_1/util/text_styles/text_style.dart';

class UpdateStatusScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  UpdateStatusScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.docID,
    required this.selectedStatusType,
    required this.statusName,
    required this.startDate,
    required this.endDate,
    required this.statusID,
  });

  late TextEditingController statusName;
  late String? selectedStatusType;
  late String startDate;
  late String endDate;
  late String docID;
  late String statusID;

  @override
  State<UpdateStatusScreen> createState() => _UpdateStatusScreenState();
}

CollectionReference db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');

class _UpdateStatusScreenState extends State<UpdateStatusScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _statusTypes = [
    "Select status type...",
    "Excuse",
    "Leave",
    "Medical Appointment",
  ];

  void initState() {
    display();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _showStartDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateFormat("d MMM yyyy").parse(widget.startDate),
      firstDate: DateTime(1960),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if (value != null) {
          widget.startDate = DateFormat('d MMM yyyy').format(value);
          editUserStatus();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void _showEndDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateFormat("d MMM yyyy").parse(widget.endDate),
      firstDate: DateTime(1960),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if (value != null) {
          widget.endDate = DateFormat('d MMM yyyy').format(value);
          editUserStatus();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  void editStatus() {
    editUserStatus();
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  Future editUserStatus() async {
    db.doc(widget.docID).collection('Statuses').doc(widget.statusID).update({
      //User map formatting
      'statusName': widget.statusName.text.trim(),
      'statusType': widget.selectedStatusType,
      'startDate': widget.startDate,
      'endDate': widget.endDate,
    });
  }

  void display() {
    //print(sName.text);
    print(widget.selectedStatusType);
    print(widget.startDate);
    print(widget.endDate);
    print(widget.docID);
    print(widget.statusID);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.statusName.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 21, 25, 34),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.w),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back_sharp,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 25.sp,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20.h,
                  ),
                  StyledText(
                    "Let's add a new status for this soldier ✍️",
                    30.sp,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  StyledText(
                    "Fill in the details of the status",
                    14.sp,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.h,
                  ),
                  //Status type drop down menu
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      dropdownColor: Colors.black54,
                      value: widget.selectedStatusType,
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_downward_sharp,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                      items: _statusTypes
                          .map(
                            (item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: item,
                              child: AutoSizeText(
                                item,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                    fontSize: 16.sp,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                      onChanged: (String? item) async => setState(() {
                        widget.selectedStatusType = item;
                        editUserStatus();
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30.h,
                  ),

                  //Name of status textfield
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.w),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16.sp,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                        controller: widget.statusName,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          labelText: 'Enter Status Name:',
                          labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.sp,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30.h,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      //Status start date picker
                      Container(
                        height: 55.h,
                        width: 150.w,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 15.w, vertical: 15.h),
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            widget.startDate,
                            //sDate,
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.sp),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0.sp),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            _showStartDatePicker();
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.date_range_rounded,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(
                        width: 10.w,
                      ),

                      //Status end date picker
                      Container(
                        width: 145.w,
                        height: 55.h,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 15.w, vertical: 15.h),
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            widget.endDate,
                            //eDate,
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.sp),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0.sp),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            _showEndDatePicker();
                          },
                          child: const Icon(
                            Icons.date_range_rounded,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40.h,
                  ),

                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: editStatus,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.sp),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Colors.deepPurple.shade400,
                            Colors.deepPurple.shade700,
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.r),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.add_to_photos_rounded,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 30.sp,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 20.w,
                            ),
                            AutoSizeText(
                              'ADD STATUS',
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 22.sp,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get this error when I try to type on the textfield the first time,
*W/OnBackInvokedCallback(11092): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
W/OnBackInvokedCallback(11092): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
D/InsetsController(11092): show(ime(), fromIme=true)
*
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMDPZ.png)

[You can't see it here, but the cursor is for some reason at the start of the TextFormField in the status Name feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTH4f.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you provided is related to the OnBackInvokedCallback and the InsetsController in an Android application. Here's an explanation of each component:

OnBackInvokedCallback: This callback is used to intercept the back button press event in an Android application. By enabling this callback, you can override the default behavior of the back button.

InsetsController: Insets are areas of the screen that may be reserved for system UI elements, such as the status bar or navigation bar. The InsetsController allows you to control how these insets are displayed or hidden.

Regarding the error message you're seeing, it indicates that the OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for your application. The suggested solution is to set the 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback' attribute to 'true' in your application's manifest file. By doing this, you enable the callback and allow your application to handle the back button press event.

As for the log message you mentioned about "show(ime(), fromIme=true)," it seems to be unrelated to the error message you provided. This log message is related to the Input Method Editor (IME) and indicates that the IME is being shown or made visible. The "fromIme=true" part might indicate that the IME is being triggered from the IME itself.

If you're encountering issues with your text field or unexpected behavior related to showing the IME, it could be unrelated to the error message you provided. More information about your specific code implementation or context would be helpful to provide a more accurate solution.

Comment: That explained a LOT! Thanks your.
Do you by any chance know how to set the onbackinvodedcallback to true? I cannot find materials online